# Recursive star power of java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to answer this question but I can't seem to get it to come back right. I understand this will be really easy but I can't seem to get this. This is in java.

Write a recursive method starString that  accepts  an  integer  parameter n
and returns  a String object  of  length 2n(i.e.,  2  to  the nth  power)  containing stars (asterisks). 
For example: Please ignore the dashes this was for formating. I just need to send back what is in `""`

> Call--------------------- Output  -------------------- Reason
>
> `starString(0);`------ `*`  -------------------- `2power0 = 1`
>
> `starString(1);`------ `**` -------------------- `2power1= 2`
>
> `starString(2);`------ `****` --------------------`2power2= 4`

You  may  assume  that `n>0`.    Note  that  your  method  body  must  not  use  iteration

Here is what i have:

```
private static String star(int n){
    if (n==0){
        String b ="*";
        return b;
    }
    else {
        String b ="**";
        n-=1;
        star(n);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: First read up on recursion. If we provide the answer here. It will not help you  to understand that

Comment: Possible hint: `"*"` + `"*"` => `"**"` / `"**"` + `"**"` => `"****"` / etc

Comment: I agree with @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne. I myself struggled with recursion a couple of months ago, and wanted to understand the concept and how to work with it. [This website](http://codingbat.com/java/Recursion-1) helped me get a good understanding of recursion. I haven't completed all tests (yet) but I found it really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any `n > 0` you always return `"**"`, and just ignore the result of `star(n)` call, which is wrong.
The correct version would be:

```
private static String star(int n) {
  if (n==0) {
    String b ="*";
    return b;
  } else {
    String t = star(n-1);
    return t + t;
  }
}
```

Comment: don't spoon-fed the answer. Then he will not take a attempt to understand the concept.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The stars will be exactly the length of `n + 1`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Why do you think so? `star(0) --> *`, `star(1) --> **`, `star(2) --> ****`, etc. It's what required, isn't it?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne agree

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I believe your edit has the same answer as before .. doesn't: n -= 1; String t = starString(n); == String t = star(n-1);

Comment: @Vladimir S. 2 to the power of 3 must give 8 stars, not 4. By the way, your `star(2)` will not be `****` but `***`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi `star()` is zero-indexed so `star(2)` gives 4 stars and `star(3)` gives 8 stars - which is correct. What this answer does not do is handle negative numbers.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Once again, my `star(2)` will be `****`, `star(3)` will be `********`, as needed. You can copy-paste and run this program, and check results.

Comment: @MT0 OP explicitly said you can assume n > 0.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to see `return t + t;`, I didn't downvote you anyways.

Comment: @pjs But the OP already violated that constraint in the ealier sample output section with `starString(0)` - IMO, its better to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: @MT0 I read that as the instructor stating that this won't be invoked by the end-user with n < 1, so no checking is needed.

Comment: @spaga Since you said this solution works, could you pls mark is as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
private static String startStar(int n) {
    if (n==0) {
        return "*";
    } else {
        return startStar(n-1)+startStar(n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's way more efficient to call the recursion once and double the result.  Your solution does 2**n-1 recursive calls.

Comment: @pjs, what about case when n=0? When you double the result you will receive 2 instead of 1.

Comment: First, OP explicitly said n > 0.  Second, if called with 0 you wouldn't be in the else clause where the doubling should occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static String starString(int n) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (n == 0) {
        return "*";
    } else if (n < 0) {
        try {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can't pass a value less than 0");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught an IllegalArgumentException: " + e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
    } else {
        return starString(n - 1) + starString(n - 1);
    }
}
```